# No errors while running but nothing shows up at all. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

I am a beginner and I was trying to make a simple web browser following a tutorial. When I run the code there are no errors and python opens but nothing shows up on screen. I am using PyCharm. This is the Code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class MyWebBrowser():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setWindowTitle("swells browser")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal = QHBoxLayout()

        self.url_bar = QTextEdit()
        self.url_bar.setMaximumHeight(30)

        self.go_button = QPushButton("Go!")
        self.go_button.setMinimumHeight(30)

        self.back_button = QPushButton("Back")
        self.back_button.setMinimumHeight(30)

        self.forward_button = QPushButton("Forward")
        self.forward_button.setMinimumHeight(30)

        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.url_bar)
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.go_button)
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.back_button)
        self.horizontal.addWidget(self.forward_button)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        self.go_button.clicked.connect(lambda: navigate(self.url_bar.toPlainText()))
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.browser.back)
        self.forward_button.clicked.connect(self.browser.forward)

        self.layout.addLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))

        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.window.show()

        def navigate(self, url):
            if not url.startswith("http"):
                url = "http://" + url
                self.url_bar.setText(url)
                self.browser.setUrl(Qurl(url))


app = QApplication([])
window = MyWebBrowser
app.exec_()
```

I have looked through the code and I can't find anything wrong that would make it so nothing shows up. It is as if the widgets are not being added or something. I am not sure.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're not instantiating MyWebBrowser. You forgot the parenthesis:
`window = MyWebBrowser()`

Comment: Thats annoying, but now I know. Thank you!

Comment: That's also a typo, and, as such, off topic on StackOverflow. I suggest you to delete your question at once, as it will be probably closed in the near future and automatically deleted sooner or later.